# How Can I Build wxWidgets With Eclipse On Windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, cygwin, wxwidgets

I installed wxWidgets 2.8.9 on a Windows XP SP2 box and built the library according to the directions and now I'm trying to get the [Hello World! tutorial](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hello.htm) app to build from within Eclipse and I'm just missing something apparently.  Any idea how to get Cygwin, Eclipse and wxWidgets to play nice together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [answer](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.wxwindows/browse_thread/thread/2771869bdadbf576/28e8011930924b64?lnk=st&q=eclipse+wxWidgets#28e8011930924b64) was posted by Lars Uffmann to the comp.soft-sys.wxwindows newsgroup.  In a nutshell:

1. Add c:/cygwin/usr/local/bin to the path in the Eclipse project configuration
2. Add ``wx-config --cxxflags`‘ to the GCC C++ Compiler command
3. Move the ${FLAGS} variable to the
   end of the GCC C++ Linker Command
   Line Pattern
4. Add ``wx-config --libs`‘ to the GCC
   C++ Linker flags.

Thank goodness for Mr. Uffmann sharing this information; this problem has been giving me headaches for days.

---

EDIT: Note that there is a literal backtick at each end of the wx-config strings.  The method of escaping the backtick doesn't seem to work correctly. Refer to the linked answer for more details on exact syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I built wxWidgets with MinGW on Windows myself and let CMake 2.6 create the Makefiles and project files for Eclipse on Windows. This works pretty well for me.